# Make exception to smooth scrolling script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this script to make smooth scrolling on a page with a lot of anchors.
But when I'm adding Bootstrap's accordions, they don't work (they don't collapse/expand) due to this script.

How can I make some adjustments to the script, so that it doesn't collide with the accordions collapsing/expanding?

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card stats">
    <h4 class="card-header" role="tab" id="statsHeading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stats" href="#collapseStats" aria-expanded="false">Header</a></h4>
    <div id="collapseStats" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="statsHeading">
      <div class="card-block">
        Content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nLkvfh4n/).

Comment: `$('a[href*="#"]')` is causing the problem, add some class to all the other anchors (other than accordian anchors) and use `$('a.someclass[href*="#"]')`

Comment: I actually did the exact opposite of that, because I believe it's easier to target just the accordion links as opposed to all the other links. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a class `accordion` to the Bootstrap accordion links you can then exclude this from the selection in your scrolling function by using `.not()`.

**HTML**

```
<a class="accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stats" href="#collapseStats" aria-expanded="false">Header</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a[href*="#"]').not('.accordion').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: yes it will do great. Extra words for the comment to post

Comment: Yes, i'd prefer this approach. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Update your html code with my code and problem will solve. please check and confirm. Here I just make changes in  tag if you check my code and I hope then you understand what is the issue :)

```
    <div id="stats" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card stats">
    <h4 class="card-header" role="tab" id="statsHeading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stats" href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="#collapseStats" aria-expanded="false">Header</a></h4>
    <div id="collapseStats" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="statsHeading">
      <div class="card-block">
        Content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```